# .01 ETH bounty to whoever can help identify where I sent my ETH

Tags: transactions, ether

Back in Feb I sent my ETH somewhere (to one of my wallets or an exchange) to update my hard wallet firmware. I'm normally ultra-careful and send test transactions but I may have been intoxicated when I did this. I somehow sent with extremely low fees and I incorrectly thought the transaction didn't arrive in the following days. Recently I found that the translation did succeed. Problem is, I don't know where I sent it. I have lots of old accounts, wallets and exchanges. I thought I sent it to coinjar but it never arrived there so maybe not. Might have been metamask but I only have the recovery seed and not the private key. Dunno.

Anyone who can correctly help me identify where the coins are will be sent .01 ETH.

Many many thanks in advance.

Transaction [etherscan link](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0b3b2acff5a8bf4f19ab9822e87d9faf66307c21a554c6b4100645a102d34629)

Transaction details are below:

```json
{
  "tx": {
    "nonce": "0xa",
    "gasPrice": "0x2540be400",
    "gas": "0xc350",
    "to": "0x5236d25394b4ab91F543041D2E62c69067983DFC",
    "value": "0x4563918244f40000",
    "input": "0x",
    "hash": "0x0b3b2acff5a8bf4f19ab9822e87d9faf66307c21a554c6b4100645a102d34629",
    "blockNumber": "0xbff4da",
    "from": "0x24a71F7E5774443498B5932A9c58D18153F1a023",
    "transactionIndex": "0x79"
  },
  "receipt": {
    "gasUsed": "0x99ed",
    "status": "0x1",
    "logs": [
      {
        "address": "0xd6a062CAE6123C158768A5C444CA0896CC60D6B1",
        "topics": [
          "0x6e89d517057028190560dd200cf6bf792842861353d1173761dfa362e1c133f0"
        ],
        "data": "0x0000000000000000000000005236d25394b4ab91f543041d2e62c69067983dfc0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004563918244f4000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "address": "0x5236d25394b4ab91F543041D2E62c69067983DFC",
        "topics": [
          "0x69b31548dea9b3b707b4dff357d326e3e9348b24e7a6080a218a6edeeec48f9b"
        ],
        "data": "0x00000000000000000000000024a71f7e5774443498b5932a9c58d18153f1a0230000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004563918244f4000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: By looking up [the transaction hash on etherscan](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0b3b2acff5a8bf4f19ab9822e87d9faf66307c21a554c6b4100645a102d34629), I can see that you sent 5 ether to [this address](https://etherscan.io/address/0xd6a062cae6123c158768a5c444ca0896cc60d6b1). That address appears to have only been mentioned once on the internet, by [a reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/binance/comments/8n04t5/eth_deposits_generated_from_smart_contracts/dzt86z3/) that seems to suggest that it's related to an Australian crypto exchange.

Comment: I found another mention of that address, in a [bitcointalk forum post](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5279042.msg56204652#msg56204652). I don't know what to make of it, though.

Comment: I think you have it. Binance. For whatever reason it hasn't gone into my account there. I can't believe I didn't think of just googling the address! Can you message me an address to send the bounty?

Comment: What did you use to send those ethers ? Binance doesn’t support internal transactions (ie transfer coming from a contract, like multisig for instance), brace yourself, your Binance Support journey will soon begin…

Comment: @Emer Please donate the bounty to the Electronic Frontier Foundation, [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x095f1fD53A56C01c76A2a56B7273995Ce915d8C4) ([verification](https://www.eff.org/pages/other-ways-give-and-donor-support)). Thank you and good luck!